# React state value became null when it pass to model

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have AboutMeText state and it successfully updated by props, I successfully display its value `<h6>{this.state.AboutMeText}</h6>` but when I try to pass this state value into model its value became null. I already tried
`{this.state.AboutMeText}` or `{this.props.AboutMeText}` but not work

Please help me sir i am new in react js

```
 <DIV className="template-profile">
   <Image
     url={this.state.selectedImages.profilePicture}
     mode={"Profile"}
   />
   <h6>Hello I'm</h6>
   <h1 className="template-profile-name">
     Nabnit Jha
   </h1>
   <h6>
     {this.state.AboutMeText} // here state value display successfully
   </h6>
   <DIV className="template-self-info">
     <Modals modalBody={this.state.AboutMeText} modalHeading="About Me"></Modals> // here state value became null
   </DIV>
 </DIV>
```

Comment: are you opening your model on any click or on load?

Answer (score 0):

if I correctly understand your problem.
You need set default state for avoid null data

if you use class component in constructor of class you should set default value of state

```
class SomeComponent extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
         someData: []
    };
   }
}
```

if you use functional component you should use react hooks

```
const SomeComponent = () => {
   const [items, setItems] = useState([]); // default value empty array
};
```

Comment: Sir I already assign defult value

AboutMeText: this.props.AboutMeText
        ? this.props.AboutMeText
        : "Describe about yourself here..."

Answer (score 0):

Open your model based on condition like -

```
               <DIV className="template-profile">
                    <Image
                        url={this.state.selectedImages.profilePicture}
                        mode={"Profile"}
                    />
                    <h6>Hello I'm</h6>
                    <h1 className="template-profile-name">
                        Nabnit Jha
                    </h1>
                    <h6>
                    {this.state.AboutMeText} // here state value display successfully
                    </h6>
                    <DIV className="template-self-info">
                        {modelStatus&&<Modals modalBody={this.state.AboutMeText} modalHeading="About Me"></Modals>}
                        //here state value became null
                    </DIV>
                </DIV>
```

function to make it true

function `clickHandle`

```
clickHandle=()=>{
  this.setState({modelStatus:true})
}
```

You use your function based on your requirement.

Comment: Sir i already set modelStatus true and model open even modalHeading value also display only modalBody not data not display mean AboutMeText value

Comment: render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Button variant="primary" onClick={() => this.setModalShow(true)}>
                    Read More
                </Button>

                <MyVerticallyCenteredModal
                    show={this.state.modalShow}
                    onHide={() => this.setModalShow(false)}
                    modalHeading={this.state.modalHeading }
                    modalBody={this.state.modalBody }
                />
            </div>
        );
    }